# Add attributes to elements in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a

```
<div ng-repeat="post in getServerPosts()" >
```

where i ng-bind post.title and post.excerpt. Posts also have unique a post.id but it is not shown (which is what I want since I don't bind it).

I am trying to find a way to allow the user to mark a post by somehow utilizing the post.id. That way, if a user marks a post it will automatically be marked next time the ng-repeat runs (every time the page loads).

I have played around with scopes in the controller but I can't figure out how to handle the post.id this way.

Question is probably beyond newbie level and maybe there are smarter ways to do this. Any hint or advice?

Comment: So, you need some button in each post, and the ng-click of the button should mark the post, by sending a request to the server, and setting some flag in the post: `<button type="button" ng-click="mark(post)">Mark this post</button>`

Comment: thank you for the reply! the posts are read by many different people on their phones (its a cordova app) so i'm looking for a way to handle it client-side.. could you elaborate on the mark(post) function?

Comment: If you don't want to persist the change on the server, then it's even easier: just set a flag in the post: `post.marked = true;`. But of course, the change won't be persistent then: as soon as the user reloads the page/application, the marked posts won't be marked anymore.

Comment: yeah that's how far i got. so i'd definitely need to send a request to the server to make it persistent? could it be an option to make it persistent by recognizing the post.id client-side, even if it's loaded again? and could a scope function handle this? i feel rude spinning on the original question but i'm waist-deep here... if anyone freelance i'll happily outsource this (sorry if this violates any rules)

Comment: You could use localStorage to store the marked posts, but the user (and the browser) is free to clear its localStorage any time. Or maybe use a native persistence API exposed by cordova, if such an API exists. A JavaScript function can do whatever it needs to do.

Comment: i'll give that a try. i don't know how to upvote or rep you or whatever but thank you very much for assisting